# Changing WooCommerce Permalink

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

After installing the language files from WooCommerce, the site's permalink becomes non-english.  I have found `Product permalink base` & `Product category base` & `Product tag base` & `Product attribute base` in the permalink setting page.

However, where is the settings for `shopping cart` & `checkout page` & `my account`?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have installed woocommerce pages, in your admin area go to "Pages" and look for the pages you want to change permalink, all is there. I think if you change your desired page **Slug**, you'll get the answer. Woocommerce works with **Page ID** and changing that slug makes no problem and just changes the **URL**.